# Is it possible to route heroku-rails-app to a subdirectory of my custom domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, heroku

I want to setup a rails app on heroku that is part of a website.
The website which is hosted on a different server explains the usage of the app, shows a tour, plans, contains a blog on related stuff and so on.

I want to route to **my_domain/app** and the app should respond to that url. The custom_domain add-on doesnt allow to enter directories.

How can I configure that or how would you realize that scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku **must** run the rails app in the root of you domain.

You can however, run the app as a subdomain and use a wildcard DNS: app.my_domain.com